# using Rider's new plugin for Specflow to build project and create .feature.cs file

Tags: c#, specflow, rider

when I build my project it should create test.feature.cs file near to test.feature file so I can create new steps in testSteps.cs class.

But when I build my project it is not creating test.feature.cs file.

any one familiar with this issue?

for an example in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEeVU0z26u0 youtube video 12:08 you can see he builds projects and gets that .feature.cs file

Answer (score 0):

so I just added [Binding] to my testSteps.cs file and now i am able to create steps from the feature file even i dont have .feature.cs file. looks like rider hided it with new updates that's why i dont see. but even without it i can create steps now.